# What is the best way to read and write purely binary information in Go?

Tags: go

I want to implement Huffman coding by hand for a personal project. The part I am stuck on is how to store the coding. Say my input can be encoded using 65 bits. Do I make a class which wraps a byte slice of 9 bytes, and treats the elements as one continuous piece of memory? Or is there a way to do what I want more directly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking (although others might be). Can you give more details about what you're trying to do? Also, there are no classes in Go.

Comment: Im trying to understand how to store binary data, of unknown length. I mean class in the informal sense (I know you use the keyword "type" in Go). If I have 65 bits, how do I store them contiguously?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you need to operate on it. You could certainly use a slice (or array) of 9 bytes to store 65 bits. You can think about creating an interface that allows you to operate on that 65-bit value in whatever way you need to operate on it. That may give you a better idea of how you should represent it internally. If you're going to have several of these 65-bit values that represent some stream of bits, you'd probably want to do it some more efficient way than wasting a whole byte to store one bit.

Comment: I think this will be very helpful. https://github.com/32bitkid/bitreader

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use bitarray data structure for this. Check out this https://godoc.org/github.com/golang-collections/go-datastructures/bitarray